# Button not performing segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Trying to perform a segue "toLogin" when the login button is pressed. Segue is named and I control-dragged the button to the block of code to make sure they are associated. Very new to coding and not sure where I went wrong.

Currently, when button is pressed it changes color but does nothing. I also previously set it to print something when pressed but that never occurs either. 
[Screenshot of code, storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Op4J.png)

Comment: Never include code as a screenshot. Include it as text using proper code formatting. Your function isn't hooked up to the button btw. You either need to connect it through the Storyboard, which will result in the function becoming an `IBAction` or add it programatically using a `selector`.

Comment: Thanks for the etiquette advice David. Will follow it in the future.

Comment: @OliverSilverstein You should [edit] this question and show your code as text. No need to wait for your next question.

Answer (score 0):

For you to connect a button to a function, the function needs to look like below

```
@IBAction func login(_sender: Any) {

}
```

You will then need to connect to the blank circle next to the function on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your screenshot, each segue linked to the whole main storyboard as highlighted showing. Not linked to button. Remove those two segues from storyboard first, and linked each segue to `storyboard reference` or next View Controller as attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have connected your button to the **@IBAction** in your UIViewController[Connect IBAction to UIButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REKCR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are triggering segue through `UIBarButtonItem`,

**Swift 4.2**,

```
loginButton.action = #selector(login(sender:))

@objc func login(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //Perform segue
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for answering everybody. I'm still not sure what exactly my issue was but I decided to re-create the storyboard page without using UIBarItems and it worked. I'm guessing that something about the UIBar was preventing interaction.